# How Not to discard duplicates in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the below mapper & reducer, This is what i am trying to do with them
i) Read a huge file 
ii) Did some modification to the lines based on a logic and write it to a file again.

Everything works fine till i have duplicate rows in the file, "My reducer discards the duplicate row and write only unique rows", **I dont want the reducer to discard duplicate rows**

**Mapper**

```
class ChopMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {            
String record = value.toString();
IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);            
context.write(new Text(record), one);                
}
}
```

**Reducer**

```
class ChopReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
{
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{          
/*Some Operations*/
context.write(new Text(record), null);         
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over all the values and emit your record in the reducer:

```
for(IntWritable value : values) {
   context.write(new Text(record), null);         
}
```